# Get the virtual name of cluster by using listener name

Tags: .net, sql-server, failovercluster

I have a cluster with 2 nodes. I know listener name (I use it to connect to SQL server).
Is it possible to find out the virtual name of cluster programmatically?

Comment: Listener... are you using an availability group?

Comment: Frankly speaking I don't know. It is fail over cluster.

Comment: I see. In either case, a Windows cluster is involved. Connect to the server, do a 'select @@servername' to get either the cluster name or the server name (which depends on whether it's a failover cluster instance or an availability group), and then you can use whatever you'd use to talk to the cluster to figure things out from there. For example, I can do get-cluster -Name $name in powershell either by node name or by cluster name and it will get me to the right cluster.